# Yii - Oracle Connection

Tags: oracle, yii, connection

I'm trying to connect my yii project with oracle database, but nothing is working.

I have already tried this

*http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/99/using-yii-with-oracle-through-pdo/*

and this

*http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/oci8pdo/*

But none of them has worked, the page just gets blank and shows no errors that would help to debug when I print **var_dump(Yii::app()->db);**

The current connection db in config/main.php is like this

```
'db'=>array(

             'class'=>'CDbConnection',
            'connectionString' => 'oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=***)(PORT=***))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=***)));charset=UTF8;',
            'username'=>'***',
            'password'=>'***',
        ),
```

Note: '***' are correctly placed.

What's wrong? What else could I try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the path where you have the class for the connection.

```
'class'=>'ext.oci8Pdo.OciDbConnection'
```

Comment: Please use english language.